# Why iPad default launch image orientations not working (iOS 5)?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

There exists a number of questions (some answered already) that pertain to the launch images. I had no problems using launch images per se. My problem comes when trying to support multiple orientations of the launch image (portrait or landscape for my app).

The problem is this:

When i started my app dev, i used the usual default.png as the launch image.

But now i have 4 different launch images (portrait and landscape, plus their retina versions). However, with these launch imaged named different, Im seeing a black screen for the launch, no matter what orientation the device is in.

I spent a day on this. And i decided to just go with a single default.png (retina portrait) since I realized the launch image only lasts a few seconds and is not very important any way.

Alas, the curiosity is killing me.

Note: the images were named as follows (notice they are lower cased, and they also are placed under /images folder rather than at the project root folder):

default-portrait.png
default-portrait@2x.png
default-landscape.png
default-landscape@2x.png

Question:

what am i doing wrong? like i said, i went thru many online references to this problem. none of them helped for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you put them into a sub-folder.

[This document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) states:

> All launch images must be PNG files and must reside in the top level
>   of your app’s bundle directory.

The fact that you are using lowercase filenames looks a bit dodgy too...

Comment: damn. i thought this was the case. but i didn't try it because i reasoned that the default.png worked within the sub-folder!

Comment: I actually won't test this. but this is certainly something i won't forget in the future. having 4 launch images is rather silly any way.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar Perhaps you have `UILaunchImageFile` set in your `Info.plist` file?  Anyway don't worry about the organisation of your app bundle - no one looks in there anyway :)

Comment: my concern was the disk size that is consumed by having 4 images (2 of which are retina). and the key I'm using is: UILaunchImageFile~ipad

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar But I'm assuming that it works with `images/default.pgn` because it's explicitly set in the `Info.plist` file.  Looks like you can remove that key and put them into the top-level folder, using the correct names.

Comment: i don't have any key explicitly defining the default.png path, if thats what you mean.